# Blog posts have 2 urls... /site and /blog. How can I remove /site and redirect to /blog

Tags: redirects

Google is indexing 2 different urls for the same blog posts, one has /site the other correctly has /blog. Example...
www.domain.com/site/blog-post-title
www.domain.com/blog/blog-post-title

How can I get rid of /site and redirect to the respective url containing /blog?

Comment: Well.. does the blog show up in those two different URLs? And if so, why? You shouldn't be redirecting unless you're concerned about stale links. What you should do is fix the site/index template, it's showing something it shouldn't. And you should also set a `canonical` link in your blog post template header so Google doesn't get confused anyway about where the real home is.

Comment: No, it shows the home page with the /site url. But i don't know where the /site urls are coming from. Cononical links are already set in the blog post templates. But going to the /site version of the url also has a connonical link but with /site in it. I cannot figure out the "why" it's even generating a page with /site/blog-title or how Google is finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a link to the URL?  Also, I'm assuming that you probably have links to these blog posts on your homepage?

Comment: The client asked me to add the redirect, which I'm using Detour Pro for... I think due to cache some aren't redirecting and some are. This one is one not redirecting, but still don't know why /site is working.
https://www.maggianos.com/site/little-italy-favorites-october-chefs-features
https://www.maggianos.com/blog/little-italy-favorites-october-chefs-features

Comment: I'm not familiar with Detour Pro, however, I'm not understanding at all how the site/post_name even came into play that this became an issue.  Do you have a page template group for blog? I also did a google search and didn't find any blog posts with "site" as the group name.  I almost feel that if google is finding the "site/..." url then you actually have that URL somewhere in your site. As I understand it, Google only indexes links that it can find as it crawls the site.

Comment: Detour Pro is just like a redirect manager. I've inheirited this site and have never worked with EE prior to a few months ago for this site, so not sure how all the inner workings should be, however...

There is a /site group with the index set to the home page and there is a /blog group with an index to handle the main blog display and the individual entries display. If you search google for ... site:maggianos.com the 3rd result shows a /site blog entry (though because of the redirect I have setup it's going to /blog)

I really have no idea why there would be any links to /site/entry